# Добавление изображений статей в собственную папку

Tags: python, django, изображения

Есть приложение django (называется rigs) и возможность добавления записей на сайт через models.py. **Нужно сделать так, что бы при добавлении новой записи на сайт её изобрежения помещались в новую папку с названием самой статьи.** Например, я добавляю статью с названием "Bee rig" и все изображения из неё помещаются в папку под названием "Bee rig" по пути *media/rigs/Bee rig/image_0.png*. **Есть ли возможность реализации данной задумки?**
Вот models.py:

```
class Rig(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    image_0 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rigs', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rigs', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
    image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rigs', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_vanila = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('rig_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Ответ на 1 комментарий** 
Сделал следующим образом:

```
def rig_directory_path_0(instance, filename):
    return ('{}/{}').format(instance.title, 'image_0.png')

def rig_directory_path_1(instance, filename):
    return ('{}/{}').format(instance.title, 'image_1.png')

def rig_directory_path_2(instance, filename):
    return ('{}/{}').format(instance.title, 'image_2.png')
```

и прописал следующие пути для моделей:

```
image_0 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rig_directory_path_0', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rig_directory_path_1', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='rig_directory_path_2', null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
```

Но при таком розкладе у меня в корневой папке /media создаются папки с названиями /rig_directory_path_0/ и т.д.

**P.S 2** 
Вот верхняя часть файла views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Rig
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return ('{}/{}').format(instance.title, filename)

class ShowRigView(ListView):
    model = Rig
    template_name = 'rigs/rigs.html'
    context_object_name = 'rig'
    ordering = ['-date']
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_context_data(self, **kwards):
        ctx = super(ShowRigView, self).get_context_data(**kwards)
        ctx['title'] = 'MCStore Rigs'
        return ctx
                   ...
```

**Вот как я сделал:** 
models.py:

```
def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return ('rigs/{}/{}').format(instance.title, filename)
```

Всем ImageField и FileField файлам прописал:

```
image_0 = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path, null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path, null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path, null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
file = models.FileField(upload_to=directory_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

В итоге файлы помещаются по пути:
*media/rigs/{название статьи}/{название файла}*

Comment: Так а зачем вы название функции в кавычках написали в upload_to? Убирайте их.

Comment: извините, не заметил) Убрал кавычки, пробую провести миграцию, выводит ошибку NameError: name 'rig_directory_path_0' is not defined.

Comment: Функции должны быть на верхнем уровне, не в классе, забыл об этом сказать

Comment: у меня эта функция и так стоит сразу же после import строк, если вы об этом (изменения добавил выше). Так же понял, что ваш первый вариант с одним directory_path подойдёт мне лучше

Comment: Извините за задержку, функция должна быть также в `models.py`, а не во `views.py`

Comment: спасибо, всё работает, в вопрос снизу добавил полное решение если кому нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы это реализовать, нужно сделать функцию для создания пути сохранения файла:

```
# upload_to автоматом передаёт сюда объект и имя загружаемой картинки
def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return ('{}/{}').format(instance.title, filename)

class Rig(models.Model):
    # в upload_to подставляем функцию
    image_0 = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path, null=True, blank=True, default='/default_rig_image.png')
```

Но если хотите фиксированно называть картинки `image_0`, `image_1` и т.д., видимо придётся сделать три отдельные функции для каждого поля типа таких:

```
# для image_0.png
def directory_path(instance, filename):
    return ('{}/{}').format(instance.title, 'image_0.png')
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но не получилось так реализовать. В вопросе добавил изменения